# How should I set up my React Routers with Modal window?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is what I've got:

```
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/cards/:cardId'>
                <FilterbarContainer />
                <CardsLibraryContainer />
                <ModalCardContainer />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/cards'>
                <FilterbarContainer />
                <CardsLibraryContainer />
            </Route>
            <Route>
                <Redirect to='/cards' />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
```

I need my Modal window to be seen upon `FitlerbarContainer, CardsLibraryContainer`. I've tried to make this:

```
<Route path='/cards/:cardId?'>
    <FilterbarContainer />
    <CardsLibraryContainer />
</Route>
```

and to render the modal inside `CardsLibrary` but there is a bug and also I guess it's not correctly. So how should I set up this Route with Modal window. Also I need to know if it's correct to redirect the user to `/cards` or can I so that cards page is by default?